# Google Map InfoWindow won't always open in mobile mode but always opens in desktop mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile

I use "body onload" to get Google map markers using php and mysql. All markers have info windows that use "mouseover" to open them:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerComm, 'mouseover', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(markerDetails);
        infoWindow.open(map, markerComm);
    });
```

In desktop mode, mouseover will always open the info window, regardless of the number of markers. In mobile mode, however, tapping the marker will only open the info window if there are many markers, like 20+.

Here's what happens when there are only a FEW markers and when I switch back and forth from mobile to desktop mode using Chrome Developer Tools WITHOUT refreshing the page:

- Info windows always open properly in desktop mode.
- Switching to mobile mode, the info windows will not open when tapped.
- Switching back to desktop mode, they open properly again.
- Switching back and forth multiple times between modes: always works in desktop, but not in mobile.
- When an info window is opened in desktop mode, then I switch to mobile mode, the info window is still open, but it can be closed by tapping on the "x". Tapping to reopen, however, will not work.

An occasional exception occurs when the page is refreshed and started in desktop mode. Sometimes when switching to mobile mode, the info windows will open when tapped, but rarely can I get this to happen.

Watching the console log, this all appears to be some kind of a timing issue. I've tried moving the function from onload to deferring an external js file, both in the head and before the  tag, but neither helped.

Any ideas on why this happens or how to correct it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you trigger the mouseover event on a touch enabled device?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. With the mouseover info windows opened when tapped on mobile devices, and wouldn't without the mouseover. However, your response gave me the idea for the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I added a click listener, and it now works on mobile devices properly:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerComm, 'mouseover', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(markerDetails);
        infoWindow.open(map, markerComm);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerComm, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(markerDetails);
        infoWindow.open(map, markerComm);
    });
```

I had tried adding click this way but it did not work:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerComm, 'click mouseover', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

I found all I needed to do was change one line in the acfmap.js file:

original:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
```

new:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
```

Just changed mouseover to click so it would work on both mobile and desktop.